# Show that:If $A$ is a subset of topology space $(X,\tau)$, $A\in\tau\Leftrightarrow\forall B \subset X:(A\cap\overline{B})\subset\overline{A\cap B}$

Tags: general-topology

It's a problem from my first general topology textbook, on which I have spent a lot of time. This chapter introduces:

> 1. Topology and open set;
> 2. Basis and subbasis;
> 3. Some properties of point set;

I think it is a direct application of definition and properties and I have tried to start from one side but failed. The closure has two kinds of description from differtion view - "the smallest closed set" and "include the $A'$". I have no idea to continue after writing dowe the definition and attempting to use "reduction to absurdity".

This is my first time trying to write a good question after reading the "guidelines". Thank you to the suggested providers who give advice and solutions in my previous bad question.

Comment: Hint: for the "leftward" implication, consider $ B = A^c $ (the compliment of $ A $, in case you use different notation).

Comment: Hint: for the "rightward" implication, prove the contrapositive.  Can you write down the negation of the statement on the right?  (If you can't, that would be a good thing for you to review before attempting this problem.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**********Proof**********: ($\Longrightarrow$): We prove the contrapositive.  Suppose there exists $B \subseteq X$ for which $A\cap\overline{B}$ is ***not*** a subset of $\overline{A \cap B}$.   That is, there is some $x \in A \cap \overline {B}$ which is not contained in $\overline{A \cap B}$.    Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $x$.   Let $U' = U \backslash (\overline{A \cap B})$ and note that $U'$ is a (perhaps smaller) neighbordhood of $x$ which does not touch $A \cap B$.  But it does touch $B$ since $x \in \overline {B}$, so it must be the case that $U'$ (and hence $U$) is not contained in $A$.  We have now exhibited an element $x \in A$ for which no neighborhood $U$ of $x$  is contained in $A$.  Consequently $A$  is not open.

($\Longleftarrow$): We prove this directly.  Let $B=A^c$ and the condition reads

$$
A \cap \overline{A^c} \subseteq \overline{\emptyset} = \emptyset
$$

Thus $\overline{A^c} \subseteq A^c$ whence $A^c$ is closed, so $A$ is open.